# Rows.Delete is deleting from the wrong worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code setup to copy the 1st sheet and rename it after the Sheet1. After that, it is supposed to select the new sheet, delete the first 20 rows on the new sheet, and sort by column K, also on the new sheet. And it is doing that, but it is doing it on the 1st worksheet instead.

```
Worksheets(1).Copy After:=Worksheets(1)
ActiveSheet.Name = "New Name"
Worksheets(2).Select
Rows("1:20").Delete
Columns("A:U").Sort key1:=Range("K2"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
```

I have tried activating the worksheet several different ways, but none are really working. Thanks for the help!

*** *** figured it out, I was running it in the worksheet itself and not a new module.... Thanks for the help everyone! And no more using .select if I can avoid it!

Comment: Try `Worksheets("New Name").Select`

Comment: Tried the code here and works. You can probably loose Worksheets(2).select, it should already be the activesheet after copy, but that is not why it is not working for you.

Comment: Do not use `Select` method! That's bad programming practice!

Comment: I think you would be better off setting the added worksheet as a worksheet object in your code and working with that instead of depending on the activesheet. That way you do not even have to select a sheet to do something on it. (Set wks = Worksheets(Worksheets.Count) would do the trick after that you can do wks.Rows("1:20").Delete At the end of the procedure do not forget to release the worksheet with Set wks = nothing)

Comment: @Tom Kinda new to VBA but, just out of curiosity, why do you have to release the worksheet?

Comment: VBA is not very good at cleaning up. So the object reference may live on after the code has been completed. This may cause problems later on. In .NET applications there is something called the garbage collector that does the cleaning up for you. In VBA you do not NEED to do clean up yourself, but it is safer to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Using Activate or Select or ActivateSheet to specify which instance of something you want is actually a confusing way to work in VBA. This is a great example of that. I'd suggest avoiding anything with 'active' or 'select' unless absolutely essential. There's very rarely a need for it.

Try:

```
Worksheets(1).Copy After:=Worksheets(1)
Worksheets(2).Name = "New Name"
Worksheets(2).Rows("1:20").Delete
Worksheets(2).Columns("A:U").Sort key1:=Range("K2"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
```

EDIT:

```
Worksheets(2).Columns("A:U").Sort key1:=Range("K2"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
```

should be:

```
Worksheets(2).Columns("A:U").Sort key1:=Worksheets(2).Range("K2"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
```

(We didn't specify which sheet to choose K2 from)

Comment: That worked for the deleting of rows, but the column sorting is now giving me a 1004 Run-time error
*** figured it out, I was running it in the worksheet itself and not a new module.... Thanks anyway!